# Database design dilemma on connecting users with messages

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database

Here's what I came up with but I'm not sure which one of these is "the best". Perhaps there's another, better one that I may not know of. Keep in mind that I have both inbox and outbox in my app and messages deleted by either sender or recipient should still be visible to other related users unless they delete it themselves.
**Option 1 - simple ManyToMany:**
Tables:
User - just user fields
Message - just message fields
User_Message - contains 2 foreign keys: user_id and message_id

Example: When user sends a message, ONE message row is added to the Message table, and TWO rows are added to User_Message, obviously connecting sender and recipient with the added message.
 Now, this might get a little problematic when let's say I want to fetch only inbox messages because ManyToMany will fetch all of them so I came up with option 2.

**Option 2 - OneToMany:**
Tables:
User - just user fields
MessageReceived - message fields AND foreign key to user_id
MessageSent - message fields AND foreign key to user_id

Example: When user sends a message, this message is added to both received and sent tables but with different user_id. Of course senders id will be in sent table and recipient id in received table.
Now, when I want to fetch only inbox messages, I'm fetching messages from MessageReceived table and while deleting for example inbox (MessageReceived) message, copy of it still stays in MessageSent and is available to sender so everything is fine, however I feel like there's something "not cool" about this one because I'm basically keeping ALMOST the same data in both tables.

Please, let me know what do you think about this and if there is any better way to do it, I'm also listening.Thanks for your time.
**EDIT :**
Both **Madbreaks** and **Tab Alleman** provided really good and somewhat similar solutions so thanks for that. I'm gonna go with Madbreaks one, simply because I prefer to delete the relations in join table instead of keeping a 'deleted' column but that's just my taste. Nevertheless, thank you both for your time and answers.

Comment: Can a message ever have more than one sender?

Comment: Why add two rows `user_message`?  Have 3 columns, sender_id, recipient_id, message_id.  How else you going to know who the sender was vs. who the recipient was?

Comment: No, User is the sender and that's it.

Comment: How about you have one to many. Messages has two FKs pointing back to the User table. FK1 ReceivingUserId, FK2 SendingUserId

Comment: Madbreaks, yeah you're right. That makes sense but I have one question about deleting them. When recipient deletes a message, it has to stay there for the sender so is there any other way to achieve that apart from setting NULL on one of the sides?

Comment: @Adrian Poor design to put user data in the messages table.

Comment: @Adrian, that crossed my mind too but here comes the delete problem again. I'd have to basically set NULL on for example ReceivingUserId and then have some server side script that clears all messages where both ids are null.

Comment: @Madbreaks could you quickly give a reason why? Just for my learning purposes. I've done this many times before I hope it's not catastrophic!

Comment: @Sikor just an idea even if my way is the bad way to go. You could perhaps apply it to your final method of doing this. You could do a check in SQL so when you delete the FK from receiving user, if sending user FK is null then just delete the message

Comment: @Adrian how do you handle multiple recipients? Your suggestion breaks down when the relationship between users and messages goes beyond 1-1. This is an n-to-n relationship.

Comment: @Madbreaks that is true. Im my scenario all I have ever needed is 1 to 1 but I will remember that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to add 2 rows in `user_messages` for each message - have 3 columns in that table: `sender_id`, `recipient_id`, `message_id`.

**EDIT**

The deletion scenario you describe in your question, below, changes things. Instead of a n-to-n approach, you likely now have two 1-to-n relationships:

1. the relationship between sender and their many sent messages
2. the relationship between a recipient and their many received messages

I would probably have the messages table have a sender ID foreign key. I would then have a message_recipients table that maps user (recipient) ID to message ID.

Now, if a sender can delete a message but the recipients should still be able to access it (and know who the sender is), then you'll need four tables:

1. users
2. messages
3. message_sender (1-to-1 map) -- senders deleting sent messages deletes from her
4. message_recipients (1-to-n map) -- recipients deleting received messages deletes from here

It's not clear from your question whether or not this is a requirement, I only add it for completeness.  You may want a trigger or a subsequent query to determine if/when there are no remaining relationships between the users and messages tables, and at that time (possibly) delete the message itself.

Comment: As I said in my comment, just few minutes before. That makes the most sense but what about deleting? If recipient deletes the message, it has to stay there for the sender so I'd have to set NULL in recipient_id, but how am I supposed to retrieve recipient name then?

Comment: You don't mention this deletion requirement in your question.

Comment: That's because it came up with your solution so I'd like to know how to handle that.

Comment: I updated my answer. It would be good to update your question to clarify around some of these points, as well.

Comment: Thank you for an explanation, I will update my question soon as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do (I am assuming a message can only have one sender, but multiple recipients)

- UserTable - Contains UserID and Other info
- MessageTable - Has MessageID, SenderID (FK to UserTable.UserID) and other info
- MessageRecipientsTable - Has MessageID, RecipientID (FK to UserTable.UserID), and possibly other info like when/if it was received, etc.

If you want a recipient to be able to delete a message and still have it show for the sender (and other recipients), then you would add a "Deleted" column to the MessageRecipientsTable.  You would never actually delete a row from the messages table, but when populating a recipients inbox you would filter out the rows where "Deleted" is true.

Comment: This is a good solution as well. Just few minor questions if you don't mind. 1. Is this a performance increase compared to my option 2? (asking this because that's the same number of rows inserted). 2. If sender wanted to do delete the message from his outbox, I assume I'd have to make a column deleted in MessageTable ?

Comment: Well it's definitely more normalized than your option 2, so it will keep your database smaller, but whether you see a performance difference I don't know.  And yes, if you wanted the sender to be able to delete from his outbox without deleting from the recipients inbox, then you would use a Deleted column in the Message table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will update my question and accept one of the answers when I'm home which is in ~3-4 hours from now.